# Can I find only those fields which are queryable using schema

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using `schema.getGlobalDescribe()` to retrieve **Object** names and labels and further using the **Object** name to retrieve its field name, after that I'm converting the field names into a string (comma separated) but when I use it in a **Dynamic Query**, it throws an exception because it contains some fields that are not queryable. Is there a way to avoid such fields?

Comment: can you please add what concrete exception are you facing?  and code snipped with a query as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the standard classes of Salesforce - DescribeFieldResult and  DescribeSObjectResult

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Account.Industry.getDescribe();
system.debug(f.isAccessible());
```

This will tell you whether the field is Accessible to the current user or not.